# why json which is shown in browser and exported is different in firebase

Tags: firebase

The problem is, the json data structure can be different than shown in browser when you export it.

The structure I have:

```
{
  "name" : "Main Category",
  "prio" : "10",
  "subCategories" : {
    "subCategory1" : {
      "name" : "Sub Category 1",
      "products" : {
        "product1" : true
      }
    },
    "subCategory2" : {
      "name" : "Sub Category 2",
      "products" : {
        "product2" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If **subCategories** field has more than one child, data structure does not change. But, if it has only one child, here is the result:

```
{
  "name" : "Main Category",
  "prio" : "10",
  "subCategories" : [ null, {
    "name" : "Sub Category 1",
    "prio" : 1,
    "products" : {
      "product1" : true
    }
  } ]
}
```

Why does it change?

Comment: Do your sub categories have numeric keys? Such as `0`, `1`, etc?

Comment: I expect that what you're seeing is just the way that Firebase deals with arrays: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase. But I cannot reproduce the behavior based on the data you've provided: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/33074723.json